# Parse a JSON body after multipart ajax Angular call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, multipartform-data, multipart

I'm trying to parse a body that is coming to me after an api call using ajax angularJs.
After call the response is:

```
--3531b7e68196e3144197f82db0864b7e391c8b0ad51c4176c28f8ac41b3c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="passport"; filename="passport.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "Nothing",
    "dob_display": "10/11/1997",
    "dob_accuracy": "FD",
    "owner_firstname": "Nothing",
    "owner_surname": "To Understand"
}
--3531b7e68196e3144197f82db0864b7e391c8b0ad51c4176c28f8ac41b3c--
```

I didn't find a plugin to get the body from this request. Do I need to make manual parser or I could get another solution.
Can someone help me?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: See [`FormData`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-formdata)

Comment: my expected result is the json {
    "name": "Nothing",
    "dob_display": "10/11/1997",
    "dob_accuracy": "FD",
    "owner_firstname": "Nothing",
    "owner_surname": "To Understand"
} and after that to have access like an object in angular.

Comment: Not sure how you receiving the raw `FormData` as a string? Can you include `javascript` at Question which returns the string?

Comment: I'm making a call using ajax.post to server and the response is coming like I wrote this is it :(
And I need the object from that response. { "name": "Nothing" ..... }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.slice()` with `String.prototype.indexOf()` at each parameter to get indexes of `"{"`, `"}"`,  `JSON.parse()`.

```js
let response = `--3531b7e68196e3144197f82db0864b7e391c8b0ad51c4176c28f8ac41b3c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="passport"; filename="passport.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "Nothing",
    "dob_display": "10/11/1997",
    "dob_accuracy": "FD",
    "owner_firstname": "Nothing",
    "owner_surname": "To Understand"
}
--3531b7e68196e3144197f82db0864b7e391c8b0ad51c4176c28f8ac41b3c--`;

let json = JSON.parse(response.slice(response.indexOf("{")
           , response.indexOf("}") + 1));

let {name} = json;

console.log(json);
console.log({name});
console.log(name);
```

Comment: Fixed everything with a custom made parser. I will post everything below.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for parsing any form data that is coming after an API call:

```
parser = function (data) {
  // this will split --1491test9246asaery134214
  // if you have multiple files in the response
  var dataArray = data.split(/--\S*[0-9a-z]/g), response = {};
  underscore.each(dataArray, function (dataBlock) {
    var rows = dataBlock.split('\n'),
        header = rows.splice(0, 4).slice(1, 3),
        body = rows.join('');

    if (header.length > 1) {
      var patternGetName = /(".*?")/g,
          name = patternGetName.exec(header[0])[0].replace(/(")/g, '');
      response[name] = body;
    }
  });
  return response;
};
```