# Returning bytes[] and Java Object in Jersey in same Http Response

Tags: jersey-2.0

I have to return `byte[]` as file data and JSON object both in a http response from a REST service.

Also I have to process this response in `Angular 6` at front end side

The REST service uses `Jersey 2.0`

I have already implemented the Jersey Rest Service and it returns `Multipart Response`

But I am unable to process the Multipart response in Angular 6  as `HttpClient` in Angular cannot process MultiPart Response as per [Handling a multipart Response body in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058724/handling-a-multipart-response-body-in-angular)

Now , I have done exactly same thing in Spring by using org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap as below -

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> responseData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();  
SomeDto someDto = new SomeDto();
responseData.add("results", someDto); // this is JSON 
responseData.add("fileDetails", fileData); // where fileData has one of the field 
as byte[]
```

So I am able to return byte[] as well as Java Object in same Http Response.

Finally the response received at client side is JSON

How can we achieve the same thing in Jersey 2 ?

Is there any `MultiValueMap` counterpart in Jersey 2 which can be used to send both byte[] and Java Object in Jersey 2 ?

Comment: Base64 encode the byte[] and combine it with the JSON to make one JSON object. You can decode the base64 on the client side.

Comment: You don't have to make a new class to hold both objects if you don't want to. You can just put them in a Map and return the Map.

Comment: @Paul , I used first approach and it is working fine