# Handle multipart/form-data response with Angular

Tags: angular, multipartform-data, angular-httpclient

.
Hi all,

I received a multipart response from the server containing 3 parts:

1. A JSON object
2. A STL file
3. A PNG file

The boudary is BOUNDARY[image]

I tried to handle the response as a simple text, to read each part of it and create a blob for each file.
But the two file remain "corrupted" when I open them on my computer.

Here is a first snippet I created:

```
  private parseResponse(response: string): Blob {
    console.log(['response', response]);
    const dataArray: string[] = response.split(`--BOUNDARY`);
    dataArray.shift();
    dataArray.pop();
    console.log(['dataArray', dataArray]);

    if (dataArray.length !== 3) {
        throw new Error('Scan response must contain 3 multiparts -> ' + dataArray.length);
    }
    // Third one is the image
    const rows = dataArray[2].split(/\r?\n/);
    rows.shift();
    rows.shift();
    rows.shift();
    rows.shift();
    rows.shift();
    // rows.shift();
    console.log(['rows', rows, rows.join(''), response]);
    return new Blob([new TextEncoder().encode(rows.join(''))], {type: 'application/octet-stream=utf-8'}) ;
```

Thanks for your help. I'm completely lost :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling a multipart Response body in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058724/handling-a-multipart-response-body-in-angular)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed I already saw this question before asking mine and it helped me to handle the JSON part.
But now, I don't know how to handle the application/octet-stream parts. How to convert them to a blob

Comment: Can you try to take the content and create a file out of it using library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver/v/1.3.2 ?

Comment: Thank you again!
I have exactly the same file content than previously. 
FYI: the file I'm creating from the rest request is almost twice bigger that the expected file